# Perl WWW::Mechanize Comparing the response header content length of different urls

Tags: perl, hash, www-mechanize

**I have a question I'm hoping you could help with?**

I have two text files containing the following:

**FILE1.txt**

```
http://www.dog.com/
http://www.cat.com/
http://www.antelope.com/
```

**FILE2.txt**

```
1
2
Barry
```

**The output I correctly achieve is as follows:**

```
http://www.dog.com/1
http://www.dog.com/2
http://www.dog.com/Barry 
http://www.cat.com/1
http://www.cat.com/2
http://www.cat.com/Barry
http://www.antelope.com/1 
http://www.antelope.com/2
http://www.antelope.com/Barry
```

**Code to do the above**

```
    open my $animalUrls, '<', 'FILE1.txt' or die "Can't open: $!";
    open my $directory, '<', 'FILE2.txt' or die "Can't open: $!";

    my @directory = <$directory>;   #each line of the file into an array
    close $directory or die "Can't close: $!";

    while (my $line = <$animalUrls>) {
    chomp $line;
    print $line.$_ foreach (@directory);
    push (@newListOfUrls, $line.$_) foreach (@directory);  #put each new url into array
    }
```

**Now the problem I am having:**

I need to get the Content Length of the original urls (File1.txt) and compare the Content-Length of each of the new urls with the **corresponding** original one to see if they are the same or different, for example:

- I need to compare the Content-Length of http://www.dog.com/1 with the Content-Length of original url http://www.dog.com/ to see if there is a difference.
- Then I need to compare the Content-Length of http://www.dog.com/2 with the Content-Length of the original url http://www.dog.com/ to see if there is a difference.
- Then I need to compare the Content-Length of http://www.dog.com/Barry with the Content-Length of the original url http://www.dog.com/ to see if there is a difference.
- Then I need to compare the Content-Length of http://www.cat.com/1 with the Content-Length of the original url http://www.cat.com/ to see if there is a difference.
- Then I need to compare the Content-Length of http://www.cat.com/2 with the Content-Length of the original url http://www.cat.com/ to see if there is a difference.
- And so on........

**Code to get the Content-Length:**

```
print $mech->response->header('Content-Length');  #returns the content length
```

What I am having trouble with is how to compare each new url with the **correct corresponding original one? (i.e not accidently comparing the Content-Length of http://www.cat.com/Barry with the Content-Length of http://www.dog.com/)** Should I use a hash maybe and how would I go about that?

Your help with this would be much appreciated, Many Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you took our advice regarding the open. Well done! :)

Comment: @simbabque - Yeah thanks, would of been stupid to ignore it :), any thoughts on this one?

Comment: By the way, I think WWW::Mechanize might be a little oversize for this. If you only want to get to the Content-Length, I would just use LWP::UserAgent. But since Mechanize inherits from LWP::UserAgent, it doesn't make that much of a difference, really. If you feel more comfortable with Mechanize, stick to it.

Comment: @simbabque - Yeah, i understand what your saying, the only logic behind it was that this part of code will be used as part of a much larger program that I will be using lots of other mechanize code in, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a hash for this. I'd change your input code to make a more complex data structure, as this makes the task easier.

```
open my $animalUrls, '<', 'FILE1.txt' or die "Can't open: $!";
open my $directory, '<', 'FILE2.txt' or die "Can't open: $!";

my @directory = <$directory>;   #each line of the file into an array
close $directory or die "Can't close: $!";
my $newURLs;

while ( my $baseURL = <$animalUrls> ) {
  chomp $baseURL;

  SUBDIR: foreach my $subdir (@directory) {
    chomp $subdir;
    next SUBDIR if $subdir eq "";
    # put each new url into arrayref
    push( @{ $newURLs->{$baseURL} }, $baseURL . $subdir );
  }
}
```

We can now use this to our advantage. Assuming we have already set up Mechanize:

```
foreach my $url ( keys %{$newURLs} ) {
  # first get the base URL and save its content length
  $mech->get($url);
  my $content_length = $mech->response->header('Content-Length');

  # now iterate all the 'child' URLs
  foreach my $child_url ( @{ $newURLs->{$url} } ) {
    # get the content
    $mech->get($child_url);

    # compare
    if ( $mech->response->header('Content-Length') != $content_length ) {
      print "$child_url: different content length: $content_length vs "
        . $mech->response->header('Content-Length') . "!\n";
    }
  }
}
```

You could even do it without the second set of `foreach` loops by putting the code where you build up your data structure.

If you are unfamiliar with these references, take a look at [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). What we have done here is make a hash with a key for each of the base URLs, and put an array of all the generated child URLs into that. If you use Data::Dumper to output the final `$newURLs`, it will look something like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'http://www.dog.com/' => [
    'http://www.dog.com/1',
    'http://www.dog.com/2',
   ],
  'http://www.cat.com/' => [
    'http://www.cat.com/1',
    'http://www.cat.com/2',
   ],
};
```

**EDIT**: I updated the code. I used these files to test it:

URLS:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/ 
http://www.superuser.com/
```

Dirs:

```
faq
questions
/
```

Comment: this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for :), i know you said its untested, but I cant seem to get it working properly and cant work out why, if you get a chance to test it I would be extremely grateful, thanks

Comment: I think it may be something to do with the  '$mech->get($url);' part as im getting '400 URL must be absolute' and 'Use of uninitialized value $content_length in numeric ne (!=) at'

Comment: I think it may be to do with the $mech->get($url) part is only trying to get the /1 or /2 or /Barry part of the url instead of http ://www.dog.com/1 or http ://www.dog.com/2 or http ://www.dog.com/Barry ? Although I may be wrong

Comment: I believe there's something wrong with your implementation. Please post it in a gist at https://gist.github.com/ so we can take a look.

Comment: @perl-user I updated the code. You were right, there was a mistake in it. I used the wrong keys for the hash, and I also added empty keys. You could have figured that out yourself by just looking at Dumper $newURLs. ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot for the update, it was extremely helpful and works perfectly and your explanation of your answer is great, really helped me understand whats going on. Something I've not come across is the SUBDIR: part, I get the idea of what its doing, but what is it called so I can look at some docs/tutorials for it, thanks once again.

Comment: @perl-user the `SUBDIR:` is a label. You can look at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements

Comment: Hi again, another question: In the foreach loop if it found http ://www.dog.com/1 had a different content length to the original base url of http ://www.dog.com, how would I then prevent it from going on and checking if http: //www.dog.com/2 had a different content length as well (i.e stop testing that particular base url as soon as it finds one with a different content length and then move onto checking http ://www.cat.com)? Let me know if this question is unclear, thank you very much for your help

Comment: @perl-user Either `next` the outer loop or `last` the inner loop. I'd add labels to both of the loops, like the `SUBDIR:` one I used in the first code block.

Comment: thanks, exactly what I needed, I used `next` on the outerloop with a label, I'm learning a lot from your help, thanks

Comment: Also, if I wanted to the store for later use the base url's if the content length is not equal to the child url's content length (as well as just printing that they are not the same, as shown in your code) how would you go about it (i.e what is the best method of doing this?). Should I just use `push @array, $url` or is there a better, preferred method of doing this such as using another hash, thanks a lot

Comment: @perl-user I've lost track. Please ask a new question with example code and describe what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to do what you need. It stores all the URLs in `@urls` and prints the content lengths as it fetches each URL. I don't know what you need the length data for afterwards, but I have stored the lengths of each response in the hash `%lengths` to associate them with the URLs.

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;

STDOUT->autoflush;

my @urls;

open my $fh, '<', 'FILE1.txt' or die $!;
while (my $base = <$fh>) {
  chomp $base;
  push @urls, $base;
  open my $fh, '<', 'FILE2.txt' or die $!;
  while (my $path = <$fh>) {
    chomp $path;
    push @urls, $base.$path;
  }
}

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my %lengths;

for my $url (@urls) {
  my $resp = $ua->get($url);
  my $length = $resp->header('Content-Length');
  $lengths{$url} = $length;

  printf "%s  --  %s\n", $url, $length // 'undef';
}
```

**output**

```
http://www.dog.com/  --  undef
http://www.dog.com/1  --  56244
http://www.dog.com/2  --  56244
http://www.dog.com/Barry  --  56249
http://www.cat.com/  --  156
http://www.cat.com/1  --  11088
http://www.cat.com/2  --  11088
http://www.cat.com/Barry  --  11088
http://www.antelope.com/  --  undef
http://www.antelope.com/1  --  undef
http://www.antelope.com/2  --  undef
http://www.antelope.com/Barry  --  undef
```